# When not using VS designer, should I add code to Form1.designer.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am not sure about that. I do not want to use designer for many things (but for some I do). Should I write my "manual" code into the designer.cs or to form class itself?

Answer (score 2):

No, never.

Because it will be generated again and your written-code will be lost.

In order to add code to a class which has designer, you need to define a partial class with the same name.

```
public partial class Form1
{
    // here write your logic (which will be preserved).
}
```

For more info: [Partial Class (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should really not do that. Each time you change something in the designer, it will regenerate the `InitializeComponent()` method. Therefore, your changes will be overwritten by that code. The only way this would not happen is to write your code in the same way the designer does - which is almost impossible. It could also happen that your designer crashes after you changed the code and you may not know why. You should better stick with the designer.